# How can I paste text onto each page of a PDF document?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, text, itext

I'm using itextsharp to try and post text on each page of a PDF document. I've got it working so that text is pasted to the first page, but it won't work for the other pages in the document. The basic idea of what my program does is it scans in forms and saves the images to a temporary PDF doc. Each page has a special code that I want to print to the corresponding page in the new PDF doc.

Here is my code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(session.getTempDir() + "temp.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(session.getPDFDir() + session.getFile() + ".pdf", FileMode.Append));
for(int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
     PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetOverContent(i);
     cb.BeginText();
     string thisPagePrint = (String)printStrings[i - 1];
     BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
     cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 10);
     cb.ShowTextAligned(1, thisPagePrint, 4, 440, -90);
     cb.EndText();
     stamper.Close();
     reader.Close();
     File.Delete(session.getTempDir() + "temp.pdf");
}
```

As I stated above, text is only pasted to the first page, but I would like for this to work for each page in the document. Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Try to put it out of the loop 
stamper.Close(); reader.Close();
Why do you close it every time?

Comment: Chris, that did it. Amazing the obvious mistakes that don't stick out to me sometimes.